# Manifold approximations to $BO(3)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, classifying-spaces

We know that $BO(1) =\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ has closed, finite-dimensional manifold approximations $\mathbb{R}P^1\subset \mathbb{R}P^2\subset\cdots.$

Similarly $BO(2)$ can be approximated by closed, finite-dimensional manifolds, as follows. There is  a fibration
$$
BSO(2) \to BO(2) \to BO(1),
$$
where the projection is given by the determinant. Both the base space $BO(1)=\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ and the fibre $BSO(2)=\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ can be approximated by finite-dimensional manifolds. Hence the total space $BO(2)$ can be approximated by the *Dold manifolds*
$$
P(n,m) = \mathbb{C}P^n \times_{\mathbb{Z}/2} S^m,$$
where the generator of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ acts on the sphere by $-1$ and on $\mathbb{C}P^n$ by complex conjugation.

> Do similar closed, finite-dimensional manifold approximations exist for $BO(3)$?

Comment: In your examples, the approximating manifolds are closed.  For $BO(3)$, do you want your manifolds to be closed?  There are approximations of classifying spaces of Lie groups by *open* manifolds that are used, for instance, in constructing equivariant Chow theory.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Yes, I intended the manifolds to be closed, thanks for this. I'll edit.

Comment: For $BO(3)$ one can choose the Grassmannian of 3-planes in ${\mathbb R}^\infty$, and this is in some sense approximated by the finite-dimensional Grassmann manifolds of 3-planes in ${\mathbb R}^n$. What kind of approximation do you have in mind?

Comment: @AllenHatcher: That's a good point. I guess I was hoping for something similar to the Dold manifolds, using some nice approximations to $BSO(3)$. Perhaps in general one has to look at finite Grassmannians, though. I may delete the question.

Comment: Why Dold manifold's are interesting for you? Is it that you are looking for some (co)homological property? By the way, I am afraid, I didn't follow how given that above fibration, and knowing the specified manifold filtrations for the base and fibre, you are are deducing the filtration of the total by Dold? Maybe clarifying this can help to get some generalisation?!

Comment: Stasheff constructed truncated bar constructions $B_nH$. In particular $B_nS^1 \simeq CP^n$. Similarly, one can consider $B_n RP^3$ which will approximate $BRP^3$. However I am not sure if $B_n RP^3$ is a manifold.

Comment: @user51223: I want something I can at least compute the integral cohomology of. Following Allen's suggestion, $G_3(\mathbb{R}^6)$ might be in this category (although I've not found an easy reference for that yet).

Comment: @MarkGrant This actually might be far from what you said. But, at odd primes $BO(2n)$ and $BO(2n+1)$ are homotopy equivalent, as well as $BO(2n+1)$ and $BSO(2n+1)$ that might be found in 

Emery Thomas `On the cohomology of the real Grassmann complexes and the characteristic classes
of n-plane bundles' Trans. Amer. Math. Soc., 96:67–89, 1960.

So, perhaps you only have to deal with $p=2$. So, doesn't this allow to use the filtration for BO(2) together with some extra piece?! I also appreciate that a filtration by finite Grassmanns, as mentioned by Allen, is the most natural object to look at.

Comment: @user51223: In response to your first comment, because we can view $BO(2)$ as the total space of the Borel fibration $BSO(2)\times_{\mathbb{Z}/2} S^\infty$.

Comment: $BSpin(3)$ has the very nice representation $\mathbb H\mathbb P^\infty$. The fiber sequence $BSpin(3)\to BSO(3)\to K(\mathbb Z/2,2)$ suggests that $BSO(3)$ is on par with $K(\mathbb Z/2,2)$. ($BO(n)$ reduces to $BSO(n)$ in a way independent of $n$.)